# PyMySQL Error inserting values into table. - Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am trying to make a login system with python and mysql. I connected to the database, but when I try to insert values into a table, it fails. I'm not sure what's wrong. I am using python 3.5 and the PyMySQL module.

```
    #!python3
    import pymysql, sys, time
    try:
        print('Connecting.....')
        time.sleep(1.66)
        conn = pymysql.connect(user='root', passwd='root', host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, database='MySQL')
        print('Connection suceeded!')
    except:
        print('Connection failed.')
        sys.exit('Error.')

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    sql = "INSERT INTO login(USER, PASS) VALUES('test', 'val')"

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
    except:
        conn.rollback()
        print('Operation failed.')

    conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you describe the statement "it fails" a little better?  What happens?  Do you get an exception?

Comment: Also, I don't know much about the mysql parser, but I usually see a space between the table name and the parens:  `"INSERT INTO login (USER, PASS) VALUES ('test', 'val')"`

Comment: no i handled the exeption with the try/except statement. if i remove the statement, this is what i get -  (1054, "Unknown column 'USER' in 'field list'")

Comment: @k_user can you please share the error you're getting if you remove the `except` block?

Comment: when i remove the try/except block i get this error -       pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'USER' in 'field list'")

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have to do with the order of the statements in the connection. According to the PyMySQL github (found [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py)) the correct order is host, port, user, passwd, db.

Comment: Doubtful -- default arguments should be able to be supplied in arbitrary order when calling by keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
user = input("User: ")
pass = input("Pass: ")
sql = "INSERT INTO login(USER, PASS) VALUES('%s', '%s')"%(user, pass)
```

btw you should connect like this :

```
 conn = pymysql.connect(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    user='root',
    passwd='root',
    db='MySQL
    )
```